# How to prevent char arrays from being overwritten from for loops when using strcat

Tags: c

Whenever a word from wordlist passes as a valid word, strcat(code,wordlist[i]) is called to add the word to world list.

So if at the first line "am" is put, code=am.
Or if abhcgmsopa bqcedpwon abmnpc abcdponm dfajbbmmn cabnmo is put at the first line, the three corresponding valid words are put.

However at the second line the values in code get overwritten and extra characters are put, even though code is initialized outside the while-loop and strcat should append the values to the end of code. Then when the while-loop ends, code is replaced by the entirely by "xq", where x was the first letter put into code and q is from "quitting".
Code isn't reinitialized or changed aside from what is appended to it.
How can I prevent this?

Thanks

*Edit: I defined some stack functions before the main but edited it out here to minimize the code

```c
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char input[300];
  char code[]="";
  int ci;

     /* set up an infinite loop */
 while (1)
 {
   //break;
   /* get line of input from standard input */
   printf ("\nEnter input to check or q to quit\n");
   fgets(input, 300, stdin);

   /* remove the newline character from the input */
   int i = 0;
   while (input[i] != '\n' && input[i] != '\0')
   {
      i++;
   }
   input[i] = '\0';


   /* check if user enter q or Q to quit program */
   if ( (strcmp (input, "q") == 0) || (strcmp (input, "Q") == 0) )
     break;

   /*Start tokenizing the input into words separated by space
    We use strtok() function from string.h*/
   /*The tokenized words are added to an array of words*/

   char delim[] = " ";
   char *ptr = strtok(input, delim);
   int j = 0 ; 
   char *wordlist[300];


    while (ptr != NULL)
    {   
        wordlist[j++] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);

    }

   /*Run the algorithm to decode the message*/
   //j=words in line;i=i-th word we are evaluating
   //k=k-th letter in i-th word

   stack1 st;

   for(int i=0;i<j;i++){

      //stack1 st;
      init(&st);
      for(int k=0;k<strlen(wordlist[i]);k++){
         if((int)wordlist[i][k]<101 && (int)wordlist[i][k]>96){ //check if this letter is a/b/c/d with ascii
            push(&st,&wordlist[i][k]);
            printf("%c added\n",st.ptr[st.inUse-1]);
         }
         else{
           if(wordlist[i][k]==top(&st)+12){ //check if letter is m/n/o/p corresponding to a/b/c/d from top()
             pop(&st);          
           }
         }
      }
      if(is_empty(&st)){
        printf("%s is valid\n",wordlist[i]);
        strcat(code,wordlist[i]);
        strcat(code," ");

      }
      else{
        printf("%s is invalid\n",wordlist[i]);
        clear(&st);

      }
      printf("code:%s\n",code);
   }
   printf("code after loop: %s",code);
 }
 printf("code: %s\n",code);
 for(int i=0;i<300;i++){
   if ((int)code[i]<101 && (int)code[i]>96){
     printf("%c",code[i]);
   }
   if(!((int)code[i]<96+26 && (int)code[i]>96)){
     printf(" ");
   }
 }
 printf("code:%s",code);
 printf ("\nGoodbye\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't show your code, we can't help you.

Comment: The code[] array is not big enough.  Use char code[300]="";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `code` variable is an array of 1 character! This line:

```
char code[]="";
```

declares it as an empty string (no characters) plus a null terminator.

You need to assign it as an array big enough to hold the maximum possible answer! If this is, say, 500, then use this:

```
char code[500]="";
```

Comment: How can I limit the for loop at the very end to print the characters I need then? Instead of all the 300 allotted? And thank you kindly. Hours passed..

Comment: @thegoodhunter-9115 Stop the loop (or break out of it) when `code[i]` is zero: e.g. `if (code[i] == 0) break;` (inside the loop).

Comment: So in the 300 characters a null or zero is stored? Does strcat handle that?

Comment: Yes! You initialize your `code` string to `""`, which puts zero (`nul` character) in its first element; all subsequent calls to `strcat(code, xxx)` will ensure that, after appending the `xxx`, the string will still be null-terminated.